# Should cypress npm package be installed locally?

Tags: npm, cypress

I'm building  a CI/CD pipeline for end to end testing where devs would use multiple instances of cypress, in different servers and well local env. To avoid installation problems , as well version conflicts should the npm packages installed local or global? or should they be already installed in repository but defined versions in json package then all the person needs to do is clone and run?

Comment: I'd avoid installing Cypress on any CI/CD server. We should start a container for every build and run Cypress tests inside it.
https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/docker.html#Images

Comment: The best way (for me), because of CI/CD, is to not have cypress as a dependency at all(neither dev-dependency)! All other useful packages you're coding with in cypress test code does not contain an npm dependency to cypress, so it's possible. This way, on CI/CD it won't be installed, and only in a specific testing environment, such as GitHub actions, using a special container image having cypress globally preinstalled/cached, you can invoke your cypress tests automatically there.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Cypress via `npm` (or `yarn`) and have cypress listed in your  `package.json` `devDependencies`.

This way, someone only needs to clone the repo, run `npm install`, and they'll have Cypress installed.

Here's the Cypress Docs on [Continuous Integration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html)

Comment: But wouldn't this be an overhead on non testing environment where it will install cypress which downloads the entire chrome binary

Comment: Cypress will only install the binary once per system, storing the binary in a user-data directory